# Ubuntu phone android tv tablet?

Tags: android, ubuntu-touch, tablet, phone, tv

I am a bit confused (about Ubuntu touch/phone/android/tv/tablet).

1. Is the Ubuntu OS for phone the same as Ubuntu for Android
2. If I have a phone with Ubuntu (touch) on it, how do I use it to connect it to a monitor (and connect a keyboard/mouse) ? Will the phone behave as a PC or will the swipe stuff still swipe (I have *no* touchscreen/monitor, just a plain ol' tft monitor)
3. Can I hook the phone to my TV and watch movies? (not without a streaming device/pc right? I have a laptop right now hooked to the TV with a HD filled with movies, isn't that a better way of watching movies?

Thnx for your response!

Answer (score 2):

1. No. Ubuntu for phone uses *some* parts which are also used in Android/CyanogenMod. Ubuntu for Android is an Ubuntu on top of an existing and functioning Android.
2. This is not yet implemented. It it clearly planned that the phone connected to Keyboard Mouse and Monitor behaves like a PC.
3. This is also not yet implemented. But from what I can see right now there will be a lot of openness so reasonable solutions will be available. And as long as there is a physical connection from your phone to your TV I am positive that there will be a solution to play a video directly from your phone.